# behavior of storing string in bytea across postgresql-8 & postgresql-12

Tags: postgresql-12, postgresql-8.4

currently I am migrating the postgres database from pg8 to pg12, but I have encounter with a new issue

> previously in pg8

```
 create table test (id int, data bytea);
 insert into test values (1,'hello world');
 table test;      

  id |    data
 ----+-------------
   1 | hello world
 (1 row)
```

> Now in pg12

```
 create table test (id int, data bytea);
 insert into test values (1,'hello world');
 table test;

 id |           data
----+--------------------------
  1 | \x68656c6c6f20776f726c64
(1 row)
```

> I want same behavior as pg8 as describe above. can anyone have an idea how should I achieve that.
>
> and also why this behavior is different across different version? can anyone explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set in *postgres.conf* to escape the bytea output

```
 bytea_output = 'escape'
```

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-binary.html